# Temp table doesn't exist error using nested aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use nested aggregation for one of my queries:

```
SELECT t.type, t.avgrent
FROM (  SELECT e.type, AVG(e.rental_rate) AS avgrent
        FROM Equipment e
        GROUP BY e.type) AS t
WHERE t.avgrent IN (SELECT MIN(t.avgrent) FROM t)
```

And I keep getting the following error:

> DB query error: Table 'database.t' doesn't exist

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not reuse `T` like that. Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT t.type, t.avgrent
FROM (  SELECT e.type, AVG(e.rental_rate) AS avgrent
        FROM Equipment e
        GROUP BY e.type) AS t
WHERE
    t.avgrent IN
(
    SELECT
        MIN(t2.avgrent)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
           e.type, 
           AVG(e.rental_rate) AS avgrent
        FROM Equipment e
        GROUP BY e.type
    ) AS t2
)
```